# AWS Cognito - Users lost "non-mutable" attribute "email_verified"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

After using Cognito for a few months, some users in a user pool have now lost the "email_verified" attribute. I can't understand how it is missing or how to recover.

Symptoms are:

- Users can still login
- User password can not change (eg via [JS SDK - changePassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)), produces error: "x-amzn-errormessage: Cannot reset password for the user as there is no registered/verified email or phone_number"
- Getting the user attributes for the user with the [list-users CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/list-users.html) shows the attribute is missing

  ```
  aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id MYID-123 --query 'Users[?Username==`error@bla.com`].[*]'
  [
    [
      [
          "error@bla.com", 
          true, 
          "CONFIRMED", 
          1522127817.526, 
          1522127819.369, 
          [
              {
                  "Name": "sub", 
                  "Value": "123123123341241238"
              }, 
              {
                  "Name": "email", 
                  "Value": "bla@bla.com"
              }
          ]
       ]
    ]
  ]
  ```

  vs. one with the attribute in place

  ```
  aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id MYID-123 --query 'Users[?Username==`bla@bla.com`].[*]'
  [
    [
      [
          "bla@bla.com", 
          true, 
          "CONFIRMED", 
          1524048734.588, 
          1524048737.777, 
          [
              {
                  "Name": "sub", 
                  "Value": "1231231231231235"
              }, 
              {
                  "Name": "email_verified", 
                  "Value": "true"
              }, 
              {
                  "Name": "email", 
                  "Value": "bla@bla.com"
              }
          ]
        ]
     ]
   ]
  ```

If I try deleting the attribute (with enough permissions), it fails - as one would expect - explaining it is not mutable.

```
aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user-attributes --user-pool-id MYID-123 --username test2@test.com --user-attribute-names email_verified

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the AdminDeleteUserAttributes operation: Cannot modify the non-mutable attribute email_verified
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not find the cause for this problem, other than blaming AWS Cognito.

A workaround/hack/patch is to add the attribute back, this time, the non-mutable check is not a problem

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id MYID-123 --username error@bla.com --user-attributes Name=email_verified,Value=true
```

And now the user has the attribute again and I can reset the password.

Comment: Is there another user with the email address with email_verified set to true? That is are there 2 users with the same email address, one with email_verified = false and one with email_verified = true?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the example in the question "one with the attribute in place"

Comment: Clarification: there are users with `email_verified = true` but they don't have the same email address as ones that have `email_verified = false` or missing. Now after these last months, the `email_verified` attribute was set to `false` again in the same problematic users.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 users with same email address, and `email_verified` is true for one and not the other, it is possible it is an issue with your client code.

When you call `confirmRegistration` the first parameter is the confirmation code and the second is a boolean: `forceAliasCreation`. If set to true, then if a user already exists with the email address that is being used to register with, the new user "steals" the email address of the existing user.

It's not obvious this is a problem cause the Cognito API docs show examples of `confirmRegistration` with `forceAliasCreation` as true and not explaining what the parameter does (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js - Use Case 2, assuming you are using JS). We ran into this problem with our app and this was the culprit.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look. Apologies for the other reply it's not exactly like this, since instead of being false by "stealing" , the attribute actually disappeared.