# Cannot modify the non-mutable sub

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-cognito

Im trying to create a golang module that backs up a cognito userpool !
I fell on an error that says :

```
error creating users: operation error Cognito Identity Provider: AdminCreateUser, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: ce4c6aba-badd-4edc-8767-5ee3337abab0, InvalidParameterException: Cannot modify the non-mutable attribute sub
```

Although, seen terraform aws documentation, "sub" attribute needs to be non-mutable!
is there anyway I could fix that?

thank you.

Comment: try by adding attribute back. Refer this link it might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718209/aws-cognito-users-lost-non-mutable-attribute-email-verified and https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/2203

Answer (score 0):

`sub` is a special attribute. You can not modify the `sub` even if you have not mentioned `sub` as non-mutable, while creating the user pool. `sub` is always non-mutable and only Cognito service can create this attribute and assign it to a user.

I understand that you are creating backup of users in a new user pool. I would like to mention, a `sub` value is specific to an user pool. If you create a user in new userpool, then the `sub` value will be different for that user, and Cognito will generate that value (you can not provide it with AdminCreateUser API call). However, in the new userpool you can create a custom attribute called `old_sub` and can store the sub value of the other user pool.